# Defining requirements for hypothetical-invention questions

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

The idea of a [hypothetical-invention](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothetical-invention) tag seems to be gaining mild acceptance:

https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1167/58

If we're going to have this tag, we should probably first establish what guidelines questions of this type will need to follow, to mitigate the proliferation of low quality questions. Once we settle on some standards here, we can add them to the tag wiki.

So, feel free to jump in with any suggestions below.

Comment: This seems pretty nebulous to me.  I'm not sure how we can extend this tag without opening up to the realm of engineering fantasy.

Comment: @Tristan I'm open to better suggestions on the tag. You should look over the original question that spawned this. The problem is that we have a category of questions that a subset of users don't like, but some of which have general acceptance from the community. We need a way to categorize them so that the subset of users that doesn't like them can use the ignore tag feature.

Comment: I totally agree that we don't want to further encourage problematic questions though, that was one of my points on the other thread.

Comment: It seems like a lot of these stem from "why do we do it X way and not Y way?"  Would something like [tag:design-alternatives] be more apropos and maintain focus while avoiding turning this sub into World Building?

Comment: @Tristan That might help divert a lot of them. Let me go do another list.

Comment: @Tristan Suggested [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1170/58).

Comment: Marked this declined to indicate that we went with a different tag idea.