# How did we end up with a hypothetical tag? Should we keep it, or not?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Lo and behold, we have a [hypothetical](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothetical) tag! I spotted it on [this hypothetical question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39096/12102) but it's on three questions total.

Hypothetical questions can sometimes be asked here if the answer can be based solidly or at least mostly in fact, but should there be a tag for this?

I noticed that [Defining requirements for hypothetical-invention questions](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/12102) is `status-declined`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been discussed extensively before, see [Would a “Speculation” tag be useful?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/would-a-speculation-tag-be-useful/1167#1167), and the linked questions and discussions.

The preferred tag, in the cases where the question is on topic is [design-alternative](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-alternative). It was selected over [hypothetical-invention](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothetical-invention) and [hypothetical-scenario](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothetical-scenario). [hypothetical](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hypothetical) is even more ambiguous than the two.

We don't want this tag.

Comment: Okay thanks! I've removed it from the thee questions, presumably it will dissipate back into tag-aether in a day or so.